# How to install Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop in Ubuntu 12.04 version. Following the instructions from 
http://michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/, I installed `java-6-openjdk` from Ubuntu software-center. I have set `java_home` in `.bashrc`. Also set `java_home` in Hadoop `conf/env.sh`. While formatting the namenode, I am getting the following error:

```
usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java no such file or directory.
```

---

Thank you. But it's a 64bit OS.

Comment: Why is there a bounty when the user has found the solution? What kind of answer is expected?

Comment: @green7 The intention is to find an answer that actually is marked as accepted, is highly detailed, and the likes.  Since there doesn't seem to be one, I can understand Jorge adding the bounty.

Comment: @TheLordofTime The detailed answer would atmost contain 5 lines as the question is too localized. And if an answer containing the installation instructions for Hadoop is expected, it would be redundant as the link mentioned in the question explains it wonderfully. Moreover since the answer, with the most votes, was posted by the asker him/herself, it is very unlikely he/she would accept any other answer.

Comment: @green7 if the question is too localized then vote to close it as such?

Answer (score 40):

The guides I followed when I had 12.04 were:

- [Hadoop 2 Deployment on Ubuntu](http://dasunhegoda.com/hadoop-2-deployment-installation-ubuntu/1085/)
- [Michael Noll's Hadoop (Single Node)](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)
- [MyLearning Hadoop on Ubuntu 12.04 (Single Node)](http://www.mylearning.in/2012/10/installing-hadoop-on-ubuntu-1204-single.html)

I was actually opposed to the MyLearning one because the first thing it recommended was Oracle Java 7 instead of OpenJDK 7, but I had some issues with OpenJDK 7 when trying this out so I had to go with Oracle.

The guide is mostly straight forward and here it is:

1. Install Java

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java  
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade  
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
   ```
2. Create Hadoop user

   ```
   sudo addgroup hadoop  
   sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hduser
   ```

   Where hduser is the Hadoop user you want to have.
3. Configuring SSH

   ```
   su - hduser   
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
   cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

   To be sure that SSH installation went well, you can open a new terminal and try to create ssh session using `hduser` by the following command:

   ```
   ssh localhost
   ```

   reinstall ssh if localhost does not connect (you may need to add `hduser` to sudo as below step)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-server
   ```
4. Edit Sudoers

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```
5. Add at the end the line to add hduser into sudoers

   ```
   hduser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
   ```

   To save press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, type <kbd>Y</kbd> and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
6. Disable IPv6

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
   ```

   Copy the following lines at the end of the file:

   ```
   #disable ipv6  
   net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1  
   net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1   
   net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
   ```

   If you face a problem telling you, you don't have permissions, just run the previous command with the root account (In case sudo is not enough. For me it was)
7. Now reboot.

   You can also do `sudo sysctl -p` but I rather reboot.

   After rebooting, check to make sure IPv6 is off:

   ```
   cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
   ```

   it should say **1**. If it says **0**, you missed something.
8. Installing Hadoop

   There are several ways of doing this, the one the Guide suggests is to download from the [Apache Hadoop site](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/core) and decompress the file in your `hduser` home folder. Rename the extracted folder to `hadoop`.

   The other way is to use a PPA that was tested for 12.04:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hadoop-ubuntu/stable  
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade  
   sudo apt-get install hadoop
   ```

   NOTE: The PPA may work for some and for others will not. The one I tried was to download from the official site because I did not know about the PPA.
9. Update `$HOME/.bashrc`

   You will need to update the `.bashrc` for `hduser` (and for every user you need to administer Hadoop). To open `.bashrc` file, you will need to open it as root:

   ```
   sudo gedit /home/hduser/.bashrc
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo nano /home/hduser/.bashrc
   ```

   Then you will add the following configurations at the end of `.bashrc` file

   ```
   # Set Hadoop-related environment variables   
   export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hduser/hadoop  

   # Set JAVA_HOME (we will also configure JAVA_HOME directly for Hadoop later on)`
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
   ```

   Now, if you have OpenJDK7, it would look something like this:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java-7-openjdk-amd64
   ```

   The thing to watch out for in here is the folder where the Java resides with the AMD64 version. If the above does not work, you can try looking in that particular folder or setting the Java that will be in used with:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config java
   ```

   Now for some helpful alias:

   ```
   # Some convenient aliases and functions for running Hadoop-related commands  
   unalias fs &> /dev/null   
   alias fs="hadoop fs"    
   unalias hls &> /dev/null  
   alias hls="fs -ls"  

   # Add Hadoop bin/ directory to PATH  
   export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
   ```
10. Configuring Hadoop

    The following are configuration files we can use to do the proper configuration. Some of the files you will be using with Hadoop are (More information in [this site](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop)):

    `start-dfs.sh` - Starts the Hadoop DFS daemons, the namenode and datanodes. Use this before start-mapred.sh

    `stop-dfs.sh` - Stops the Hadoop DFS daemons.

    `start-mapred.sh` - Starts the Hadoop Map/Reduce daemons, the jobtracker and tasktrackers.

    `stop-mapred.sh` - Stops the Hadoop Map/Reduce daemons.

    `start-all.sh` - Starts all Hadoop daemons, the namenode, datanodes, the jobtracker and tasktrackers. Deprecated; use start-dfs.sh then start-mapred.sh

    `stop-all.sh` - Stops all Hadoop daemons. Deprecated; use stop-mapred.sh then stop-dfs.sh

    But before we start using them, we need to modify several files in the `/conf` folder.

    **hadoop-env.sh**

    Look for the file `hadoop-env.sh`, we need to only update the JAVA_HOME variable in this file:

    ```
    sudo gedit /home/hduser/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh
    ```

    or

    ```
    sudo nano /home/hduser/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh
    ```

    or in the latest versions it will be in

    ```
    sudo nano /etc/hadoop/conf.empty/hadoop-env.sh
    ```

    or

    ```
    sudo nano /etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
    ```

    Then change the following line:

    ```
    # export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-sun
    ```

    To

    ```
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
    ```

    Note: if you get `Error: JAVA_HOME is not set` Error while starting the services, you forgot to uncomment the previous line (just remove #).

    **core-site.xml**

    Now we need to create a temp directory for Hadoop framework. If you need this environment for testing or a quick prototype (e.g. develop simple hadoop programs for your personal test ...), I suggest to create this folder under `/home/hduser/` directory, otherwise, you should create this folder in a shared place under shared folder (like /usr/local ...) but you may face some security issues. But to overcome the exceptions that may caused by security (like java.io.IOException), I have created the tmp folder under hduser space.

    To create this folder, type the following command:

    ```
    sudo mkdir /home/hduser/tmp
    ```

    Please note that if you want to make another admin user (e.g. hduser2 in hadoop group), you should grant him a read and write permission on this folder using the following commands:

    ```
    sudo chown hduser:hadoop /home/hduser/tmp  
    sudo chmod 755 /home/hduser/tmp
    ```

    Now, we can open `hadoop/conf/core-site.xml` to edit the hadoop.tmp.dir entry.
    We can open the core-site.xml using text editor:

    ```
    sudo gedit /home/hduser/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
    ```

    or

    ```
    nano /home/hduser/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
    ```

    Then add the following configurations **between `<configure>` xml elements**:

    ```
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/home/hduser/tmp</value>
      <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
      <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
      scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
      uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
      the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
      determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
    </property>
    ```

    Now edit **`mapred-site.xml`**

    ```
    <property>
      <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
      <value>localhost:54311</value>
      <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
      at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
      and reduce task.
      </description>
    </property>
    ```

    Now edit **`hdfs-site.xml`**

    ```
    <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
      <description>Default block replication.
      The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
      The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
      </description>
    </property>
    ```
11. Formatting NameNode

    Now you can start working on the Node. First format:

    ```
    ~/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
    ```

    or

    ```
    ./home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
    ```

    You should format the NameNode in your HDFS. You should not do this step when the system is running. It is usually done once at first time of your installation.
12. Starting Hadoop Cluster

    You will need to navigate to hadoop/bin directory and run the `./start-all.sh` script.

    ```
    cd ~/hduser/hadoop/bin/  
    start-all.sh
    ```

    If you have a different version from the one shown in the guides (Which you will most likely have if doing this with the PPA or a newer version) then try it this way:

    ```
    cd ~/hduser/hadoop/bin/   
    start-dfs.sh  
    start-mapred.sh
    ```

    This will start a Namenode, Datanode, Jobtracker and a Tasktracker on your machine.
13. Checking if Hadoop is running

    There is a nice tool called `jps`. You can use it to ensure that all the services are up. In your hadoop bin folder type:

    ```
    jps
    ```

    It should show you all Hadoop related processes.

    NOTE: Since this was done around 6 months ago for me, if there is any part not working let me know.

### Hadoop Using Juju (A Juju Charm for Hadoop)

Taken from [Charming Hadoop](http://javacruft.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/charming-hadoop/)

I will assume the following is already set up:

- You have a server with Juju already set
- You have access to the server (Locally or remotely)
- You have Juju configured and ready to start adding charms
- You are using 12.04 (This is because I tested all of this with 12.04)
- You have already configure `~/.juju/environments.yaml` with the information regarding the server you will be using including the PPA origin.

Ok now follow this steps to have a Hadoop service running:

1. Bootstrap the environment for Hadoop

   ```
   juju bootstrap
   ```

   Wait until it finishes then check to see if it is connecting correctly:

   ```
   juju status
   ```
2. Deploy Hadoop (Master and Slave)

   ```
   juju deploy --constraints="instance-type=m1.large" hadoop hadoop-master   

   juju deploy --constraints="instance-type=m1.medium" -n 5 hadoop hadoop-slave
   ```
3. Create Relations

   ```
   juju add-relation hadoop-master:namenode hadoop-slave:datanode  

   juju add-relation hadoop-master:jobtracker hadoop-slave:tasktracker
   ```
4. Expose Hadoop (Since you already deploy and created relations the service should be running)

   ```
   juju expose hadoop-master
   ```

   And check status to see if it working correctly:

   ```
   juju status hadoop-master
   ```

Up to now you have a running Hadoop. There are many more things you can do that can be found in the link provided or in the official [Juju Charm for Hadoop](http://jujucharms.com/charms/precise/hadoop)

For up to date JuJu Charms (Setups, Step by Step guide and more) you can visit: [JuJu Charms](https://jujucharms.com) and make your own JuJu Environment and see how each file is setup and how each service connects.

Comment: ["You should be using gksu to launch graphical things as root."](http://askubuntu.com/a/216680/25798)

Comment: `hduser (ALL)=(ALL:ALL) ALL`  throws syntax error...

Comment: try with `hduser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, remove the first pair of brackets

Comment: The path of the `hadoop-env.sh` isn't inside the `hduser`. Insted, it is `/etc/hadoop/conf.empty/hadoop-env.sh`

Comment: @ssoto just checked and yes. Maybe they changed it in the latest versions.

Comment: Would you recommend to use `juju` in order to instantiate hadoop? I'm spending a lot of time configuring hadoop. I suposse that at the begining, while you are learning a technology that's common.

Comment: As things have been going with JuJu, I would even recommend making coffee with it. I added at the bottom of the answer a link for you. In that site you can setup any JuJu Charm and see how each file is configured and how each service talks to each other apart from many other data that the site will help you deploy and setup.

Comment: I get an error message when I try to run a simplistic streaming job: hduser@ubuntu:~$ sudo hadoop jar /usr/share/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.2.jar -input ~/test.txt -output ~/xxx.txt -mapper /bin/cat -reducer /bin/cat
14/04/22 18:31:19 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 0 time(s).

Comment: May I know why we need to call `sudo apt-get update` twice by linking them with `&&` synctax?

Comment: The 2nd update lines is optional for anyone that ones to use the PPA, there are other alternatives. The 1st one is to update and upgrade the system in one line. The 2nd line just shows the same line because we added an additional PPA (which is optional depending on who wants to use it).

Comment: `.bachrc` – wait till [Johann Sebastian](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Sebastian_Bach) hears that. Oh wait, he can't… because he's deaf. :-D

Comment: Is this tutorial still up to date ?

Answer (score 6):

I successfully installed Hadoop by setting the path of `JAVA_HOME` as `usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64`.

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive ?

Answer (score 3):

Derived from @Luis Alvarado's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/279623/22308), here is my version for Ubuntu 14.04 and Hadoop 2.5.1

## In brief

1. Install Java
2. Prepare an *executive user* for Hadoop `hduser`
3. Switch to `hduser` from now on
4. Allow `hduser` to remote via ssh with pass-phrase-less
5. Disable IPv6
6. Download and config Hadoop package
7. Prepare system path $HADOOP_HOME and $JAVA_HOME
8. Config Hadoop's services
9. Start Hadoop's services

Done. Good luck!

## Detail steps

### Install Java

Download and install

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java    
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade    
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Make sure you have Java7 installed

```
$ which java
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
```

we should have `java` point to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java`

### Prepare an *executive user* for Hadoop `hduser`

**Create user `hduser` in group `hadoop`**

```
$ sudo addgroup hadoop  
$ sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hduser
```

**Grant `hduser` the *sudo* privilege**

Edit sudo

```
$ sudo visudo
```

Add to the end this line

```
hduser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

### Switch to `hduser` from now on

```
$ su - hduser
```

### Allow `hduser` to remote via ssh with pass-phrase-less

Install openssh

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Generate RSA public/private key for SSH connection; passphrase is empty as `parameter -P ""`

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Make sure `hduser` can ssh remote locally without a password

```
$ ssh localhost
```

### Disable IPv6

Edit the configuration file

```
$ sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Copy to the end

```
#disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1   
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Make sure IPv6 is off by a reboot or call

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Then call

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

It should say 1 which means OK ^^

### Download and config Hadoop package

Download Hadoop 2.5.1 packages from [Apache Hadoop site](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/core)

The direct URL for this package is this link

```
http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.5.1/hadoop-2.5.1.tar.gz
```

So let's download to `hduser` 's home folder, extract it, and rename it to `hadoop`

```
$ wget http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.5.1/hadoop-2.5.1.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf hadoop-2.5.1.tar.gz
$ mv hadoop-2.5.1 hadoop
```

Make sure we have Hadoop stored in `hduser` home

```
$ ls /home/hduser/hadoop
```

### Prepare system path $HADOOP_HOME and $JAVA_HOME

Edit `hduser` 's .bashrc file

```
$ nano .bashrc
```

Put to the end values for `$HADOOP_HOME` and `$JAVA_HOME`

```
# Set Hadoop-related environment variables   
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hduser/hadoop  

# Set JAVA_HOME (we will also configure JAVA_HOME directly for Hadoop later on)
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Add the Hadoop `binary` folders to system `$PATH`

```
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$PATH
```

Open a new terminal, log in as `hduser`, and make sure you have $HADOOP_HOME with available commands

```
$ echo $HADOOP_HOME
$ which start-all.sh
$ which start-dfs.sh
$ which start-yarn.sh
```

We should see the full path of those names.

### Config Hadoop's services

Each component in Hadoop is configured using an XML file.

- Common properties go in **core-site.xml**
- HDFS properties go in **hdfs-site.xml**
- MapReduce properties go in **mapred-site.xml**

[image]

These files are all located in folder **$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop**

Define, again, JAVA_HOME in `hadoop-env.sh` by edit the line

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Define Hadoop `temp folder` and `file system` name in **core-site.xml** at

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hduser/tmp</value>
    <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
    <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
    scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
    uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
    the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
    determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
  </property>
  ...
</configuration>
```

We need to prepare this `temp folder` as configured at `/home/hduser/tmp`

```
$ cd /home/hduser
$ mkdir tmp
$ chown hduser:hadoop tmp
$ chmod 755 tmp
```

Define `file system` 's `block replication` in **hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>Default block replication.
    The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
    The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
    </description>
  </property>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Define `map-reduce job` in **mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:54311</value>
    <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
    at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
    and reduce task.
    </description>
  </property>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Format `name node`

```
$ hdfs namenode -format
```

### Start Hadoop service

Call

```
$ start-dfs.sh && start-yarn.sh
```

these two commands are located at **$HADOOP_HOME/sbin** which we have added to system $PATH before.

Make sure Hadoop services are started properly

```
$ jps
```

we should see

[image]

Comment: Very nice guide to follow. There is a minor mistake: `mapred-site.xml` does not exist at the beginning. It should be created by `cp mapred-site.xml.template mapred-site.xml`

Answer (score 1):

To be able to install `sun-java` with the `apt-get` command, you need to add a line to a file called `sources.list`. This file can be found in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Open the file using this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then at the very end of (bottom) of that file, you copy/paste the line:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy multiverse
```

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit, and <kbd>y</kbd> for saving.

---

Now type the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And when that is done, you can successfully run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more up to date tutorial (not sure on differences) look at the [hadoop screencasts](http://hadoopscreencasts.com/) video tutorials. They provide video and the actual commands to install underneath. Also if you email the writer he is very happy to respond and help you out if you get stuck with anything.

These instructions are largely similar to the ones that @Luis replied with.