# Unable to launch gedit with sudo

Tags: sudo, gedit, x11

While trying to follow [these instructions](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution), I encountered the following error while attempting what seems like a simple `sudo` edit operation:

```
$  sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status

** (gedit:14898): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=0bd873023a78bdb34ca1b9650000000b --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
Cannot open display: 
Run 'gedit --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
```

Running the same without `sudo` correctly launches gedit, but of course without editing ability. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: A quick workaround would be to use a console-based editor such as `nano` or `vim`, which should work without complications. I'm unsure what is causing the error - I had assumed `DISPLAY` was unset but testing this gives me a different error.

Comment: And moral of the story is to stick with documentation from known sources such as https://help.ubuntu.com/community

Comment: @vasa1 how is that the moral of the story? Regardless of the merits of following random instructions from the internet, `/var/lib/dpkg/status` is a file which I should be able to edit with gedit, but currently cannot. Please, if you have a useful answer add it below.

Comment: Hey, did you get a solution for this? Am having the same problem here.

Comment: Found a solution. Check this out http://askubuntu.com/questions/414785/cant-open-gedit-as-root/414810

Answer (score 7):

You should be using `gksu` to launch graphical things as root.

```
gksu gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of this. However, using this I get the error `Cannot open display`. I believe this is an error coming from `gedit` itself.

Comment: @BillCheatham That doesn't tally with the situation. If running `gedit` from the same terminal works, `gksu gedit` should work. Anyway, try `gksu gedit --display=:0 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: Hmm.. I agree that it seems like it should, but it just doesn't. `gedit` opens `gedit`, `gksu gedit` gives an error! I think the problems run deeper than I first thought. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1527590) in 16.04 preventing root gedit from displaying the menu bar, making it somewhat useless.

The solution is to preserve environment variables while launching gedit. (Nautilus and Terminal have the same problem and fix, by the way).

```
gksu -k gedit
```

Comment: This works but the terminal is spammed with error messages.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you can add this to the command: 2>/dev/null

Comment: You can also prefix any command with `nohup` for the same effect.