# Switching Juju lxc bridge

Tags: 13.04, juju, network-bridge, lxc

I've set up Juju running in LXC, and I'm attempting to expose it to the internal network. I'm generally following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281530/running-juju-on-a-local-server?rq=1) question to point lxc to my existing bridge (`eth-br0`).

I've edited `/etc/default/lxc` and `/etc/lxc/default.conf` as per the post, but when I try to bootstrap I get:

```
2013-09-26 19:47:05 INFO juju.provider.local environprovider.go:32 opening environment "local"
2013-09-26 19:47:05 ERROR juju.utils network.go:37 cannot find network interface "lxcbr0": net: no such interface
2013-09-26 19:47:05 ERROR juju.provider.local environprovider.go:48 failure setting config: net: no such interface
2013-09-26 19:47:05 ERROR juju supercommand.go:282 command failed: net: no such interface
error: net: no such interface
```

Obviously something is still trying to point to `lxcbr0` rather than the existing bridge. If I just want to expose a lxc juju to the network, is this the best way to do it and how should I configure it properly.

I can attach my `ifconfig` if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You are right something is trying to point **lxcbr0**.

Use **lxcbr0** in these files

1. /etc/default/lxc
2. /etc/lxc/default.conf
3. /etc/network/interfaces

I tried **br0** it give me the same error. After changing existing bridge to **lxcbr0** that I worked fine.

Comment: While thats true that using the default works, my original question is how do I *change* the bridge to something else. I have an existing bridge on a NIC that I need to point LXC to.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of juju includes an option in the environments yaml for specifying the network bridge:

```
# network-bridge holds the name of the LXC network bridge to use.
# Override if the default LXC network bridge is different.
#
#
network-bridge: br0
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: What version supports `network-bridge` option ? can you specify ?

Answer (score 1):

See which interface do you have by:

> ifconfig

my result is like this:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:600 (600.0 B)  TX bytes:600 (600.0 B)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7239 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8727 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:931464 (931.4 KB)  TX bytes:1701016 (1.7 MB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:198.46.159.94  P-t-P:198.46.159.94  Bcast:198.46.159.94  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

So my network interface is **venet0**. I edit my **.juju/environments.yaml** as below:

```
local:
    type: local
    network-bridge: venet0
```

and after saving it, run:

> juju bootstrap

You can see if it's running or not by:

> juju status

This is my result:

```
environment: local
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.14.1
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: localhost
    series: trusty
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
services: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The network-bridge option is only implemented for the local provider.

It sounds like maybe you are using the manual provider.

Sadly, for the manual provider, the only lxc network-bridge device which works is lxcbr0. It is a hard coded value.

I started a branch to add support for network-bridge to manual provider here:
https://github.com/jrwren/juju/commit/3ee84a3881e43181b16099d8649f879fc68f089c

But I do not know enough about the inner workings of juju and so, while it does start lxc instances, the state server stops listening on its 17070 port and the entire system is unusable.