# Error deploying services in juju local

Tags: virtualbox, juju, git

After following all the guides, I've managed to configure juju in the local environment inside a virtualbox guest machine, but after deploying any service (wordpress,juju-gui), they load to the point where I get a local IP address, but they get stuck in pending status. When I check the logs, It shows this error in every service :

```
ERROR juju runner.go:211 worker: exited "uniter": ModeInstalling {service-name}:git init failed: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH.
```

I tried to apt-get git but it didn't work...

Updated Info :

The host OS is OS X Mavericks, VirtualBox is 4.3.6 using bridged networking, Ubuntu is the latest Ubuntu Cloud 13.10. In order to install everything, first I had to add more repositories to the system (universe,multiverse,etc.), then I did an apt-get juju-local, afterwards I had to create a new bridge in order to add my local ethernet interface to the lxc container (replaced lxcbr0 with br0) and configure lxc and the juju local config to use it. Then I bootstraped, deployed and exposed a couple of services( juju-gui, wordpress) and now I'm stuck in the situation with the error. I´ve pinged my host machine and external ip and I get connectivity, so I assume that´s not the issue.

Update II : Doing more tests I found out the error is that the containers don't have internet connection, I can ping the host but not the router or any other node in the network, thus while trying to download the dependecies, in this case git, they fail to load. So the question would be how to setup lxc containers with virtualbox bridge network connection. It's similar to this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70597/using-a-bridge-an-lxc-container-cant-ping-router-but-the-host-os-can but I can ping the laptop and I'm using a briged network instead of NAT

Comment: Can you expand your question a bit, what's the host OS, what version of virtual box, what version of Ubuntu in the vm, how did you install Juju, etc.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you did this: "...I had to create a new bridge in order to add my local ethernet interface to the lxc container (replaced lxcbr0 with br0) and configure lxc and the juju local config to use it." It seems like you're changing the way LXC subsystem works and then you expect juju to use your changes. It's not clear though what where you trying to accomplish by doing it.
Have you tried following the documentation (https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/)? It should work just as well in a virtualbox VM, you won't even need to tweak the network setup.

Comment: I did it in order to access the VM from outside, following this guide : http://askubuntu.com/a/282415/239990

Comment: It is necessary in order to access the services outside of the VM, as I mentioned, I do have connectivity between host and the services, I can ping them, but then this error shows up...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that question. I added a comment there about changing the "network-bridge" setting in environments.yaml to "br0" (the same you put in lxc.network.link=). Try that and see if it will solve your issue.

Comment: Yes! I was going to write that, I discovered it by chance yesterday, but I don't understand why that works and it buggs me a bit :P

Comment: Also setting up promiscuous mode to allow all in the virtualbox bridge settings is necessary.

Comment: Doing more test, this was not the solution, I think it worked once because of a ip conflict but it is not a real solution. What needs to be done is to set up lxc containers to work with virtualbox bridge connection, which I haven't been able to do...

Answer (score 1):

I think what I'm trying to do it´s impossible because of how VirtualBox implements bridge networking, here is a post I found that comments on this : https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-users/2013-September/005696.html