# How can add the line into etc/sudoers file?

Tags: sudo, hadoop

I am getting this error:

```
visudo: >>>/etc/sudoers:syntax error near line 29 <<<
visudo: >>>/etc/sudoers.tmp unchanged
visudo: >>>/etc/sudoers:syntax error near line 29 <<<
```

I was try to hadoop installation([How to install Hadoop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144433/how-to-install-hadoop))

```
add at the end the line to add hduser into sudoers file
hduser (ALL)=(ALL) ALL
```

but it not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a user to the sudoers the correct syntax is:

```
hduser    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

If you want to add a group is:

```
%hdgroup   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```