# Unable to execute command start-all.sh in Hadoop

Tags: networking, server, 13.10, ssh, hadoop

GUYS I'm using this tutorial [How to install Hadoop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144433/how-to-install-hadoop)
I mean the one made by Luis Alvarado in one of the comments ..
So I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit 
Hadoop version is 2.2.0

Actually I'm a total newbie on Hadoop .. Its new for me and We guys are trying to work on some Big Data related project 
I count you guys.. Help me!
I know tutorial is based on earlier versions of Hadoop but I managed to make it through the 11th step!
And the output of the step is

```
root@sandesh-Inspiron-1564:/home/hduser/hadoop# sudo ./bin/hadoop namenode -format
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

14/03/24 20:29:54 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = sandesh-Inspiron-1564/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.2.0
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /home/hduser/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0-tests.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0-tests.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/junit-4.10.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-site-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.10.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0-tests.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1529768; compiled by 'hortonmu' on 2013-10-07T06:28Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_51
************************************************************/
14/03/24 20:29:54 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/hduser/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14/03/24 20:29:54 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Formatting using clusterid: CID-f3d89333-8217-48ce-9281-44b0caed76f9
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.HostFileManager: read includes:
HostSet(
)
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.HostFileManager: read excludes:
HostSet(
)
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max memory = 889 MB
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: shouldCheckForEnoughRacks  = false
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = root (auth:SIMPLE)
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO util.GSet: 1.0% max memory = 889 MB
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map Namenode Retry Cache
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory = 889 MB
14/03/24 20:29:55 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name ? (Y or N) y
14/03/24 20:30:01 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name has been successfully formatted.
14/03/24 20:30:01 INFO namenode.FSImage: Saving image file /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 using no compression
14/03/24 20:30:01 INFO namenode.FSImage: Image file /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 of size 196 bytes saved in 0 seconds.
14/03/24 20:30:01 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
14/03/24 20:30:01 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
14/03/24 20:30:01 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at sandesh-Inspiron-1564/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Now this is the error when I'm executing the command
./start-all.sh

```
hduser@sandesh-Inspiron-1564:~/hadoop$ ./sbin/start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
14/03/24 20:34:57 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/hduser/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
localhost]
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
Java: ssh: Could not resolve hostname Java: Name or service not known
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname VM: Name or service not known
have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
loaded: ssh: Could not resolve hostname loaded: Name or service not known
-c: Unknown cipher type 'cd'
The: ssh: Could not resolve hostname The: Name or service not known
might: ssh: Could not resolve hostname might: Name or service not known
stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
guard: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard: Name or service not known
stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
HotSpot(TM): ssh: Could not resolve hostname HotSpot(TM): Name or service not known
disabled: ssh: Could not resolve hostname disabled: Name or service not known
You: ssh: Could not resolve hostname You: Name or service not known
Server: ssh: Could not resolve hostname Server: Name or service not known
highly: ssh: Could not resolve hostname highly: Name or service not known
that: ssh: Could not resolve hostname that: Name or service not known
which: ssh: Could not resolve hostname which: Name or service not known
will: ssh: Could not resolve hostname will: Name or service not known
now.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname now.: Name or service not known
'-z: ssh: Could not resolve hostname '-z: Name or service not known
link: ssh: Could not resolve hostname link: Name or service not known
library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
guard.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard.: Name or service not known
fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
it: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it: Name or service not known
64-Bit: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 64-Bit: Name or service not known
try: ssh: Could not resolve hostname try: Name or service not known
',: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ',: Name or service not known
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-sandesh-Inspiron-1564.out
to: ssh: connect to host to port 22: Connection refused
warning:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname warning:: Name or service not known
you: ssh: Could not resolve hostname you: Name or service not known
fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
It's: ssh: Could not resolve hostname It's: Name or service not known
or: ssh: Could not resolve hostname or: Name or service not known
recommended: ssh: Could not resolve hostname recommended: Name or service not known
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname VM: Name or service not known
noexecstack'.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname noexecstack'.: Name or service not known
'execstack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 'execstack: Name or service not known
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-sandesh-Inspiron-1564.out
Starting secondary namenodes [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/hduser/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
0.0.0.0]
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
-c: Unknown cipher type 'cd'
Java: ssh: Could not resolve hostname Java: Name or service not known
stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
Server: ssh: Could not resolve hostname Server: Name or service not known
You: ssh: Could not resolve hostname You: Name or service not known
have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname VM: Name or service not known
fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
HotSpot(TM): ssh: Could not resolve hostname HotSpot(TM): Name or service not known
warning:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname warning:: Name or service not known
The authenticity of host '0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 89:fb:3d:98:2c:6d:03:c1:a3:de:96:3b:39:bc:ca:b3.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? loaded: ssh: Could not resolve hostname loaded: Name or service not known
stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
guard: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard: Name or service not known
library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
The: ssh: Could not resolve hostname The: Name or service not known
disabled: ssh: Could not resolve hostname disabled: Name or service not known
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname VM: Name or service not known
64-Bit: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 64-Bit: Name or service not known
try: ssh: Could not resolve hostname try: Name or service not known
you: ssh: Could not resolve hostname you: Name or service not known
might: ssh: Could not resolve hostname might: Name or service not known
the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
highly: ssh: Could not resolve hostname highly: Name or service not known
It's: ssh: Could not resolve hostname It's: Name or service not known
now.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname now.: Name or service not known
that: ssh: Could not resolve hostname that: Name or service not known
which: ssh: Could not resolve hostname which: Name or service not known
guard.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard.: Name or service not known
link: ssh: Could not resolve hostname link: Name or service not known
library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
or: ssh: Could not resolve hostname or: Name or service not known
with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
recommended: ssh: Could not resolve hostname recommended: Name or service not known
'-z: ssh: Could not resolve hostname '-z: Name or service not known
it: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it: Name or service not known
will: ssh: Could not resolve hostname will: Name or service not known
',: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ',: Name or service not known
'execstack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 'execstack: Name or service not known
noexecstack'.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname noexecstack'.: Name or service not known
to: ssh: connect to host to port 22: Connection refused
```

OUTPUT FOR ./start-dfs.sh

```
hduser@sandesh-Inspiron-1564:~/hadoop$ ./sbin/start-dfs.sh
14/03/24 20:57:53 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/hduser/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
localhost]
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
-c: Unknown cipher type 'cd'
'execstack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 'execstack: Name or service not known
HotSpot(TM): ssh: Could not resolve hostname HotSpot(TM): Name or service not known
now.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname now.: Name or service not known
or: ssh: Could not resolve hostname or: Name or service not known
might: ssh: Could not resolve hostname might: Name or service not known
that: ssh: Could not resolve hostname that: Name or service not known
library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
recommended: ssh: Could not resolve hostname recommended: Name or service not known
the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
it: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it: Name or service not known
with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
',: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ',: Name or service not known
link: ssh: Could not resolve hostname link: Name or service not known
you: ssh: Could not resolve hostname you: Name or service not known
disabled: ssh: Could not resolve hostname disabled: Name or service not known
The: ssh: Could not resolve hostname The: Name or service not known
have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
You: ssh: Could not resolve hostname You: Name or service not known
guard: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard: Name or service not known
guard.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard.: Name or service not known
library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
will: ssh: Could not resolve hostname will: Name or service not known
warning:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname warning:: Name or service not known
fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname VM: Name or service not known
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-sandesh-Inspiron-1564.out
to: ssh: connect to host to port 22: Connection refused
loaded: ssh: Could not resolve hostname loaded: Name or service not known
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname VM: Name or service not known
which: ssh: Could not resolve hostname which: Name or service not known
stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
'-z: ssh: Could not resolve hostname '-z: Name or service not known
try: ssh: Could not resolve hostname try: Name or service not known
highly: ssh: Could not resolve hostname highly: Name or service not known
64-Bit: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 64-Bit: Name or service not known
with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
Java: ssh: Could not resolve hostname Java: Name or service not known
stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
Server: ssh: Could not resolve hostname Server: Name or service not known
It's: ssh: Could not resolve hostname It's: Name or service not known
noexecstack'.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname noexecstack'.: Name or service not known
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-sandesh-Inspiron-1564.out
```

This output is for ./start-yarn.sh

```
hduser@sandesh-Inspiron-1564:~/hadoop$ ./sbin/start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
resourcemanager running as process 16118. Stop it first.
localhost: nodemanager running as process 16238. Stop it first.
```

Comment: The first line reads: "This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh". Did you try that?

Comment: Its giving somewhat same error see the updated post

Comment: You are showing something completely different. Please _read_ the error messages. Both errors are telling you in the first few lines to use a different program than what you are using. Try using that and if it still gives you error update your question to show us.

Comment: noe me to have the same problem, if you got solution please post it..

Comment: The problem was with the ssh keys ... use this to generate the key again `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and 
`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Answer (score 0):

Similar than [an StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674311/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-while-run-hadoop-bin-start-all-sh)
I had the same problem and I've resolved it adding to `/etc/hosts` file the next line:

```
192.168.56.101 localhost hadoop
```

where you must change the ip and change hadoop and put your own hostname.

Answer (score 0):

You have to test SSH by connecting localhost from hadoop user,

```
hadoopz@ubuntu:/$ ssh localhost
Last login: Tue Apr  1 12:02:45 2014 from localhost
```

my hadoop username is "hadoopz".

To check step by stem process follow this [link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/).