# Why do we have to call `sudo apt-get update` more than once for Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, updates

I sometimes see update commands for Ubuntu which make it twice as [this sample](https://askubuntu.com/a/279623/22308)

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

I wonder why do we have to call it twice like that? Why not just once?

Comment: Thank you! I see full clear details for me there at this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/222352/22308

Answer (score 4):

Those are two different commands. This one:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Says to update the package index file. If there is a newer version of a package available, replace it in the index.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Says to compare all the packages installed on the system to the updated package index and offer all upgrades available.

Comment: So in short, `update` is for *checking for new updates*, and `upgrade` is for *install the update(s)*. Is it right?

Comment: More or less. You can see an even more exact description with the command: man apt-get.

Comment: Thank you! Clear to me now. I see full detail here http://askubuntu.com/a/222352/22308

Comment: In short, `update` is for updating the local index of packages from the repository and `upgrade` is for performing an upgrade of all packages for which a newer version is known in the index.