# Hadoop: Not able to find the start-dfs.sh start-mapred.sh scripts

Tags: scripts, 14.10, configuration, hadoop

I have installed Hadoop [by following this tutorial.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144433/how-to-install-hadoop/279623#279623)

I installed it using ppa.

When I reached **step 12** : Starting Hadoop Cluster.

I got stuck.

When I do `cd ~/tasdik/hadoop/bin/` **It says no such file or directory**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which ppa? because `ppa:hadoop-ubuntu/stable` does not provide 14.10 packages (only 14.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial step 2 asked to create a new user: `hduser`.

So if you decided to adopt this username for the Hadoop user, the path of `start-all.sh` should be:

```
cd /home/hduser/hadoop/bin/  
start-all.sh
```

Or if installed system-wide:

```
/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/
```

Comment: If that works, please suggest an edit to the tuturial to fix the paths

Comment: I did not create a new user for it. But it's not inside that, or I am looking inside the wrong place maybe

Comment: @prodicus you could also try `sudo updatedb && locate start-all.sh`

Comment: Found it. Was inside /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/

Answer (score 1):

I have found the `start-all.sh` file on `/hadoop-x.x.x/sbin` directory.

```
path/to/hadoop-x.x.x/sbin/start-all.sh
```

where `hadoop-x.x.x` is a directory which was created on extracting the downloaded the `hadoop.tar.gz` file.

If you initiate the file, it would show

```
$ bash /home/foo/hadoop-2.7.0/sbin/start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
```

So, it's better to invoke, `start-dfs.sh` located on the same directory itself.

```
bash /home/foo/hadoop-2.7.0/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

Comment: Why downvote????