# Hadoop & Spark - why no Ubuntu packages?

Tags: aptitude, hadoop

I want to install Hadoop & Spark using `aptitude`, not the lengthy and complicated process described in [How to install Hadoop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/144433/80483).

[`hadoop-ubuntu`](https://launchpad.net/~hadoop-ubuntu) appears to have been dead for almost 2 years.

I wonder **why** Hadoop and Spark have not been packaged for Ubuntu (beyond the usual "there are no volunteers").

PS. My goal is to develop locally and deploy to a Spark server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is repo that contain hadoop and spark packages for Ubuntu:
http://bigtop.apache.org
I believe it is not always up to latest shiny release - but newer than 2 years.

```
# curl http://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-1.0.0/repos/debian8/bigtop.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bigtop.list 
# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3A367EA0FA08B173
# aptitude update
# aptitude install spark-python
```

as of now, their packages are pretty old (hadoop 2.6.0, spark 1.3.1)

Comment: looks dead to me

Comment: @sds did you try running command from this file:? http://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-1.0.0/repos/debian8/bigtop.list